# Stack traces don't have line numbers for Azure webrole projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, stack-trace, azure-web-roles

When running an Azure webrole project, stack traces for exceptions don't have line numbers. **Is it possible to have line numbers for a webrole Azure project's exceptions?** Project uses MVC.NET layout. That means controllers return the view (cshtml) files. Exceptions at the controller layer are sent to a logging method that takes in the stacktrace, but the stack traces do not have line numbers? Why? full logging is enabled. Diagnostics are enabled. Even debug is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was a bit weird. I'm going to post what happened so future users can benefit.

Check your online build settings. In our case, we had build settings that worked on our own computers, but when deploying our builds we were using an online (visual studio online) build processor. The debug settings were different on our VSO. Changing the settings on VSO to match what we had on our local machines fixed the problem.

Hope this makes sense. If anyone has any questions, I can do my best to answer them.